# There is not saved user's object in the authentication tab Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I ran the facebook auth and it works well, but When i go to the firebase authentication tab, the user is not there

[image]

Here's the code

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            print(credential)
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if let _ = error {
                    return
                }
                self.name.text = "\(user)"
                print("user is sign in")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Do i need to do any extra configuration?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you enabled the authentication method in the firebase console?

Comment: @AndréKool I have enabled facebook on user console.